Wazuh. Key "name" in the reponse get /agents
When I call Wazuh API method GET /agents in response I see key "name".
What is that? Where it stored.
It's not look lie VM name or DNS.
How I can change it?
I changed yesterday DNS name, but it doesn't help.
Thanks!
